# How to Sort an IQueryable by a list of ids

Tags: sql, linq

In mysql I can do this:

```
SELECT id, name FROM pages WHERE id IN (5, 10, 20) ORDER BY FIELD(id, 5, 10, 20);
```

What is the corresponding syntax using LINQ on an IQueryable?

Basically I'm searching with lucene.net and I want to use the returned IDs to grab the real database entries, in the specific order of relevance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var ids = new List<int>() { 5, 10, 20 };

var linqQueryResult = foo.Where(...).OrderBy(i => ids.IndexOf(i.id));
```

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 IndexOf(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: IQueryable<Store> stores = (from store in db.Stores where ints.Contains(store.ID) select store).OrderBy(i => ints.IndexOf(i.ID));

Comment: @NoPyGod: yep, it cannot be translated into expression, so if you have not much items (saying much I suppose thousands) and don't care of lazy evaluation you could put `ToList()` right before that `OrderBy()`

Comment: The number of records isn't a big deal because the search query shouldn't ever be returning that many, and if it does it's paginated anyway. I had to do ToList->OrderBy->ToList by the way. Thanks.